# How can I insert query result value into a constant string?

Tags: influxdb

For example, I queried the value of the number of hours some system has been running without downtime, and I want to return a string "the system has been running for ? hours", where ? is the value I just queried.

Comment: How to create a string like that depends on the client consuming the query from InfluxDB. We don't know anything about the language or OS, so there's no way to suggest how to do this. InfluxDB will return the query results only, there is no way to make the query engine return arbitrary strings.

Comment: @beckettsean MySQL can do that all by the database itself. So I want to know if I can do that in InfluxDB. Of course there are ways to do that in some language which is querying the database.

Comment: There is no way to do this request within InfluxDB itself. As I said, it will only return the results of the query. It cannot be configured to return anything additional.

Comment: @beckettsean Well, thank you. But why not give your answer rather than comment?

Comment: no wonder it's much less popular than mysql.

Comment: I reposted it as an answer.

Comment: The current version of InfluxDB is ~6 months old, compared to 20 years for MySQL. Of course MySQL is more popular and more feature rich. In addition, InfluxDB is solving a different problem than MySQL. If you don't have a need for InfluxDB's write throughput and data retention features, then MySQL is probably a better choice.

Comment: You are encouraged to submit [feature requests](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/new) to our GitHub repo, as this is an open source project. It seems petty of you to take a cheap shot just because the database doesn't yet have your personal pet feature. Perhaps you can contribute a pull request to get what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this request within InfluxDB itself. It will only return the results of the query. It cannot be configured to return anything additional.